# How is reactive power=VIsin(\$\phi\$)

Tags: power, ac

I know the active power is equal to average of power consume and is equal to VI cos(\$\phi\$). But how is apparent power VI and active power V sin(\$\phi\$). Is there any derivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *how is apparent power VI and active power V sin(ϕ). Is there any
> derivation.*

It's just a right angled triangle and trigonometry: -

[image]

Image from [Electrician's Journal - Understanding Power Factor](https://www.electriciansjournal.com/home/power-triangle)